# FadeIn/Out Text with click function

Tags: jquery, html, image

What I intended to do are a number of paragraphs that fadeIn and fadeOut and add a click event for each of them to be hidden and a image to fadeIn for a number of seconds, afterwards the image fadesOut and the paragraphs fade back.

I managed to do so but it's a very messy script I wrote and long, I am sure it can be done in more than half of the code I wrote but I don't know how, that's where I need you guys.

Can anyone try to optimize my code (and if "you" have the patience, explain a bit about how and why you are doing what you're doing) keeping in mind that:

*First paragraph is with the first image, secont p with second image and so on.
*I must be able to place a different amount of seconds for every image when it's displayed.

Working but LONG and messy [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/N2ELe/7/)

HTML:

```
<div id="help">
<p class="helper" id="1">Do you...?</p>
<p class="helper" id="2">Do you still...?</p>
<p class="helper" id="3">Do you really still...?</p>
</div>

<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
<div class="image3"></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
(function() {

    var helper = $(".helper");
    var helperIndex = -1;

    function showNextHelp() {
        ++helperIndex;
        helper.eq(helperIndex % helper.length)
            .fadeIn(500)
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(500, showNextHelp);
    }

    showNextHelp();

})();

$("#1.helper").click(function(){

    $("#help").fadeOut(500);
    $(".image1").fadeIn(500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.image1').fadeOut(500);
        $("#help").fadeIn(500);
    }, 500);

});
$("#2.helper").click(function(){

    $("#help").fadeOut(500);
    $(".image2").fadeIn(500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.image2').fadeOut(500);
        $("#help").fadeIn(500);
    }, 700);

});
$("#3.helper").click(function(){

    $("#help").fadeOut(500);
    $(".image3").fadeIn(500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.image3').fadeOut(500);
        $("#help").fadeIn(500);
    }, 800);

});
```

Comment: Why are you using a setTimeOut function for the fades in vanilla Javascript?

Comment: @marciano Cuz that was the only way (at the moment) I could think of for keeping my images for only some time up, if you have another way of doing it I'm open to everything.

Comment: Try adding this line instead: `$('.image1').delay(500).fadeOut(500);`
Good luck :-)

Comment: @marciano Oh, I already tried the .delay(); but is not working, for some reason is stopping the image from fading Out instead of just delaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge your three *.helper* class events into one. The id of the selector helps you.

```
<p class="helper" data-timeout-value="500" id="1">Do you...?</p>
<p class="helper" data-timeout-value="700" id="2">Do you still...?</p>
<p class="helper" data-timeout-value="800" id="3">Do you really still...?</p>

var $timeoutVariable;
$(".helper").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this),
       $id = $this.attr('id'),
       $timeout = $this.attr('data-timeout-value');

   $("#help").fadeOut(500);
   $(".image"+$id).fadeIn(500);
   $this.addClass('processing');

   clearTimeout($timeoutVariable);
   $timeoutVariable = setTimeout(function() {
      $('.image'+$id).fadeOut(500);
      $("#help").fadeIn(500);
      $this.removeClass('processing');
   }, $timeout);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: It does work but it does not meet my minimal requirements of being able to give different timeout values for each image. As you can see in my code, for my first image i have my timeout set for 500, second is 700 and third is 800.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've updated the answer. Basically I've added a data value into _helper_ element, that provides the value of the timeout. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks, I will try to dig more into jquery, any idea on where to start if I get serious with learning it?

Comment: I just thought about something...If one of my images will be set to 20 seconds timeout and i want to go back to the text fader faster with a cancel button or just to click anywhere on the screen, is that possible?...probably with clearTimeout..

Comment: I've updated the answer, the current processing _helper_ has a class named _processing_. If you add a cancel button, you can get the current helper, and show it.

Comment: Hmm, not quite working, don't know why.. http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/N2ELe/13/